# HAproxy acl rewrite not working without trailing slash

Tags: docker, url-rewriting, acl, haproxy

I'm using HAProxy to to proxy requests for an application, which has different deployments hosted in docker containers on the same machine. The end goal is to have requests to http://remote-machine/appname/deploy1 (host) proxied to http://remote-machine:810x/appname-deploy1 (docker container) without changing the url.

The following is my config file. It works as intended if I include the trailing slash (e.g. "://remote-machine/appname/deploy1/"). In this case, the URL doesn't change, and it retrieves content from "://remote-machine:810x/appname-deploy1"

If I omit the trailing slash, navigating to "://remote-machine/appname/deploy1" will incorrectly rewrite the url to "://remote-machine/appname-deploy1" and I get a 404 error since the port wasn't specified. Either way, I don't want the URL to be re-written for the user, I just need to make sure it proxies to the correct address for the app deployment.

I'm new to HAProxy, so any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
global
    daemon
    maxconn 256

defaults
    mode http
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http-in
    bind *:80

    acl deployment1 url_beg /appname/deploy1 -i
    acl deployment2 url_beg /appname/deploy2 -i
    acl app-landing url_beg /appname -i

    use_backend docker1 if deployment1
    use_backend docker2 if deploymen2
    use_backend docker3 if app-landing

backend docker1
    # We need to rewrite the url so that /appname/deploy1 proxies to /appname-deploy1 on the docker container
    # E.g. http://remote-machine/appname/deploy1 loads content from http://remote-machine:8101/appname-deploy1
    reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /appname/deploy1(.*)     \1\ /appname-deploy1\2
    server host1 remote-machine:8101 

backend docker2
    reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /appname/deploy2(.*)     \1\ /appname-deploy2\2
    server host1 remote-machine:8102

backend docker3
    reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /appname(.*)     \1\ /appname-landing\2
    server host1 remote-machine:8103
```

Comment: "*but fails without it*" In what sense does it fail?  Fails to rewrite?  Unsure whether it rewrites, but fails to work?  What do the logs on the target show? Do the targets work with direct requests to the correct path, but omitting the trailing slash?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated the post to be more descriptive. I receive a 404 without the trailing slash because HAProxy rewrites the url for the user. I want the user's url to remain unchanged, but use it to rewrite the url for the docker container I'm proxying to.